# Re-disable background for uibModal popup in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
AngularJS uibModal popup question.
I have a form where I am entering certain input fields and selecting multiple dropdown. On selection of dropdown a web API call triggers, then on submitting the form I opening uibModal popup. Till now web Api call is in pending state, popup is open and background is disabled. If user does not not perform any action on uibmodal then after 30-40 seconds response comes from web API which was triggered on dropdown selection, now the background is enabled and popup remains open.
I have two different controllers, one where popup and web API call is triggered and one for uibModal popup.
I want to re disable the background when the web API response comes.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: As always on StackOverflow, you are always much better off including actual code. (At least if you want a real answer...) But one idea could be to use events. How about you `$rootScope.$emit('WEB_API_RESPONSE_RECEIVED');` when the api call is received. And listen for that in your other controllers. `$rootScope.$on('WEB_API_RESPONSE_RECEIVED', dismissModal);` in your controllers.

Comment: Another solution could be to share a service that keep track of those things which you inject in both controllers. Anyway, that's all you get from me without sharing any code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually I am looking to re disable the background when Api response comes, i am getting the track of web api call through events.